# How can I send data from a web page to a serial port?

Tags: php, c++, curl, serial-port

I have a web page which includes a basic content. I can chance its format but it is PHP now. I want to send this data to one of the serial ports of my computer (as a visitor of PHP page).

I need a code for transferring this data from internet to one of the serial-ports. It can be C++, javascript, C# or anything else.

I am using Windows (as a visitor of web page). So, I need to send datas to serial port of visitor's computer not server's. Reading is not necessary.

Which program and process is the best option to do this properly? I need example code parts that they work just fine!

Comment: Euhm, sounds like you want to write a client for a web backend that retrieves the data from the web and then writes the retrieved data to a serial port, is that right?

Comment: boost asio is the best....

Comment: @İnsanlardanBirİnsan Then for the first part, have a look at libcurl, for the second part the C stdlib functions `write()` and `tcsetattr()` will help you out.

Comment: Please do not duplicate your questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14148981/how-can-i-send-datas-from-web-page-to-serial-port-of-visitors-computer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a library for PHP that supports writing to serial port.

See [here](http://code.google.com/p/php-serial/).

More:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php#20935

See this question for more discussion:
[How to Read RS232 Serial Port in PHP like this QBasic Program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3226979/how-to-read-rs232-serial-port-in-php-like-this-qbasic-program)

**Update:**

To do this on windows see this tutorial:
https://web.archive.org/web/20140704050547/http://blog.950buy.com/article/php-use-rs232-serial-communication-to-send-file/

Also this question: [Serial comm with PHP on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/627965/serial-comm-with-php-on-windows)

Comment: And it supports Windows! I'm surprised. EDIT: (reading is only implemented for Linux or OSX).

Comment: @DavidHarris Don't expect a lot, probably everything is `#define()`d to NOP in the source for the Windows build :P

Comment: @pzirkind you are saying that there is no any other program needed. Is PHP available to do this?

Comment: @İnsanlardanBirİnsan i updated the answer to include windows solution

Comment: @İnsanlardanBirİnsan it seems that it does have some outside dependencies (see the tutorials for more info)

Comment: @pzirkind I am using Windows but reading is not necessary. I just want to send data to port com8, com11 or more; not to com1. I am getting "failed to open stream: Permission denied" error. Is this possible with this codes?

Comment: it should be able to do that

Comment: Unfortunately, I could not be able to do that with using these tutorials. Question was changed by me, can you look at again?