# How can I send datas from web page to serial port of visitor's computer?

Tags: php, c++, curl, serial-port

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I send data from a web page to a serial port?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14147144/how-can-i-send-data-from-a-web-page-to-a-serial-port)

Is sending data from PHP web page to one of the serial ports of visitor's computer possible or not?

If it is yes, how?

If it is not, basicly, I want to write a client for a web backend that retrieves the data from the web and then writes the retrieved data to a serial port. Can you help about that?

Comment: In a word: No. Sorry. *Edit* due to some smart asses below: at least, not in a native, cross browser way.

Comment: Finally a use for ActiveX!

Comment: You will need to have software on the client computer to achieve this - it's entirely possible to do, but PHP on the server won't be able to do it - it would be rather dangerous if the HTML could run things like that on your local computer, don't you think?

Comment: @ta.speot.is `s/ActiveX/Internet Explorer/` :-P

Comment: I try to create an C++ code with using libcurl for client side but it does not work or I could not write correctly.

Comment: Just use Java, because the client would be vulnerable either way :)

Comment: @PeeHaa can you provide any references?

Comment: Please do not duplicate your own questions. Actually never ever. This only gets you downvotes and you will loose potential friends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not over the internet, as that would be very dangerous, the user would have to have special software. Otherwise web programs could (very) easily be used for malicious purposes.

Comment: Can you mention about 'special software' more? Are there any examples?

Comment: @İnsanlardanBirİnsan I have used this software before and it works well. http://www.serial-server.net