# Php serial-port data sending Linux

Tags: php, linux, serial-port

I have a little problem with PHP. I need to send some data to the serial port with PHP in Linux.

I m using this:

```
exec (" echo -ne 'hello' > /dev/ttymxc0 ");
```

it is OK but I can't see anything on my console. After I write:

```
echo -ne 'World ' > /dev/ttymxc0
```

The output is like:

```
Worldhellohello
```

Can you give me any advise or do you have suggestion about that? What should I have to do ?

Thanks...

Best Regards

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14147144/how-can-i-send-data-from-a-web-page-to-a-serial-port

Comment: Actually I looked at this page , but I think I need more simple solution because I can send data ,  but I cant see it , I can see it after I write some charachters with echo command . it s like It uses buffer or something ....